# Can't access MasterRecordId field when merging Cases

Tags: apex, case, duplicate-management, delete, merge

[image]
**SUMMARY:**
I am currently implementing **Merge Cases** functionality and need to be able to edit fields on the losing and winning record during this process. Looking at the documentation depending on whether duplicates are kept Update and Delete triggers are fired and the way to identify this as a merge operation is to check the **MasterRecordId** field on the losing record.

I am unable to access the **MasterRecordId** during the merge Case process. This is true whether the merge maintains or deletes the duplicate record.

**DECLARATIVE APPROACH:** 
When maintaining the duplicate I attempted to access it via **Validation** and **Workflow** rules (since maintaining duplicates only fires the **Update Triggers**, which is **before** the field gets populated). But the formula in the Validation field does not recognise the MasterRecordId field nor is it available to select in a workflow rule.
[image]

**PROGRAMMATIC APPROACH:** 
I have also attempted setting the merge to delete the losing record as the documentation implies that I would then be able to access the populated **MasterRecordId** field in the afterTrigger. Similar to the above paragraph that field is not available even through SOQL so I am unable to identify a merge process and make field updates accordingly

```
    public static void afterDelete(Map<Id,Case> oldMap, Map<Id,Case> newMap){
    system.debug('This is the after delete function');
    for(Case c : oldMap.values()){
        system.debug('THE DELETED CASES FROM THE MERGE: ' + c);
    }
    
    List<Case> mergedCases = [SELECT MasterRecordId FROM Case WHERE MasterRecordId != null ALL ROWS];
}
```

The debug in the above snippet does show the case I'm looking for but with the **MasterRecordId** field available and attempting to save gives us this error:
*No such column 'MasterRecordId' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.*

I have also checked the API version my Salesforce is running it does appear to be a version after MasterRecordID was added (v46).

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,
Andrew

Comment: Can you check the apiversion in the xml file of the Case trigger and this class and make sure it's > = 46.0

Comment: Hey there Manish, That actually worked, I was running an older version. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great!!. I am adding it as an answer. Accept it so that it may be helpful if some one ends up in this thread with similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MasterRecordId** is available in Case in the api version > = 46.0. If it is used in any class or trigger , make sure it's xml file has **apiversion >= 46.0**